# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' using tf =2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, url_for, redirect, session
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import array
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

IMAGE_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'img_pool')

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = IMAGE_FOLDER

def init():
    global model,graph
    # load the pre-trained Keras model
    model = load_model('sentiment_analysis_model_new.h5')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

#########################Code for Sentiment Analysis
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
@app.route('/sentiment_analysis_prediction', methods = ['POST', "GET"])
def sent_anly_prediction():
    if request.method=='POST':
        text = request.form['text']
        sentiment = ''
        max_review_length = 500
        word_to_id = imdb.get_word_index()
        strip_special_chars = re.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+")
        text = text.lower().replace("<br />", " ")
        text=re.sub(strip_special_chars, "", text.lower())

        words = text.split() #split string into a list
        x_test = [[word_to_id[word] if (word in word_to_id and word_to_id[word]<=20000) else 0 for word in words]]
        x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=500) # Should be same which you used for training data
        vector = np.array([x_test.flatten()])
        with graph.as_default():
            probability = model.predict(array([vector][0]))[0][0]
            class1 = model.predict_classes(array([vector][0]))[0][0]
        if class1 == 0:
            sentiment = 'Negative'
            img_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'Sad_Emoji.png')
        else:
            sentiment = 'Positive'
            img_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'Smiling_Emoji.png')
    return render_template('home.html', text=text, sentiment=sentiment, probability=probability, image=img_filename)
#########################Code for Sentiment Analysis

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Trying to run above mentioned code in anaconda prompt getting -

```
File "app.py", line 23, in init
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

What I have done to solve this issue? I still get the same error:

1. I changed the imports from `keras.something.something` to `tensorflow.keras.something` and the issue seemed to have gone away. Putting it here for others to benefit.
2. I tried with installation of `tf=1.14.1`

Currently using `tf== 2.4`

How to solve this issue in this version?

Answer (score 0):

Use the compatibility module

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.get_default_graph()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but as I made this change I got an error                                                            
                                                                                                                              
"ValueError: Calling `Model. predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model. predict` with eager mode enabled."    I tried with this  (run_eagerly = True) but still the same error hope you got my issue...

Comment: Thats Intresting actually, i have been using h5 models that were trained on older versions on tensorflow with no problems at all. Have you considered converting the model to pb format? I guess that will be easier to interpret than h5. And you will get rid of the dependency to keras.